Suite variables defined in __init__.robot not available in TCs of the suite
I have an RF suite setup as follows:
Suite_folder
  |- __init__.robot
  |-\service_name
    |-\Resources
    | |-myresources.robot
    |-test_cases1.robot
    |-test_cases2.robot

I intialise some suite variables in init.robot as follows:
*** Settings ***
...
Suite Setup    Prepare Test Run
*** Variables ***
@{KC_Access_Tokens}     # List that will contain the tokens needed for the suite
@{KC_Tokens_Claims}     # List that will contain the claims for all the tokens

*** Keywords ***
Prepare Test Run
    set suite variable    @{KC_Access_Tokens}    token1    token2    token3
    set suite variable    @{KC_Tokens_Claims}    claim1    claim2    claim3

When I run the suite, Prepare Test Run executes and I can see that the two lists are initialised correctly. However, both lists are empty when I try to use the inside a test case. E.g. if I check their value in test_cases1.robot:
*** Keywords ***
Check Suite Variables
    log    ${KC_Access_Tokens}
    log    ${KC_Tokens_Claims}

KC_Access_Tokens and KC_Tokens_Claims are reported empty.
Is it not possible to initialise suite variables inside init.robot?

Rename the Test keyword, Prepare Test Run to a different name from the one at suite init, or instead, just log the variables from a test case.

thank you, that was a copy / paste typo. The actual Keywords are different in init and the TCs

By default, suite variables are visible only within the current suite. However option children=True of keyword set suite variable widens their visibility to "children" suites.
With this, the following modification of init.robot fixed the problem:
*** Keywords ***
Prepare Test Run
    set suite variable  @{KC_Access_Tokens}  token1  token2  token3  children=True
    set suite variable  @{KC_Tokens_Claims}  claim1  claim2  claim3  children=True

